# Convert URL to json

Tags: javascript, json, url

I can't seem to find an answer to this question.. How can I convert a URL parameters string to JSON in javascript? I mean to ask if there is an in-built function like this or a one-liner that could do the job?

Example:

`some=params&over=here` => `{"some":"params","over":"here"}`

Comment: you using jquery ? if yes , try If you use jQuery, JSON.parse(this.yourURLString); or jQuery.parseJSON(this.yourURLString);

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2880929/502381) returns the kind of object you want.

Comment: Are you asking about a pure string to string conversion problem here?  Or are using a JavaScript server like node.js and have parameters coming in that you want to turn into an object and then, presumably, to JSON?

Comment: @RayToal I just found out that ajax pre-set data with ajaxSetup in jquery will be overwritten instead of added to a local ajax function data property if the given data is a url-type string instead of an object and I was looking for a simple way to convert that string into a json so that my default data won't be overwritten. I guess I'll just add a custom function that I've been suggested in the answers below.

Comment: Understood. Stapal's answer is fine and readable.  If you are interested in one-liners, I added an answer just for fun.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can create a method which will return JSON object

```
var params = getUrlVars('some=params&over=here');
console.log(params);

function getUrlVars(url) {
    var hash;
    var myJson = {};
    var hashes = url.slice(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        myJson[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        // If you want to get in native datatypes
        // myJson[hash[0]] = JSON.parse(hash[1]); 
    }
    return myJson;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jAGN5/

Comment: I was asking for a one-liner, but thanks for the function anyway, +rep `:)`

Comment: This does not get all values of the same parameter. For example, if the URL was 'some=params&over=here&over=there', it would not return a list for "over" param.

Comment: it converts 'isParam=true' to { isParam: 'true' }

Answer (score 6):

Try this :

```
var str = 'some1=param&some2=param2';

JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURI(str).replace(/"/g, '\\"').replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g,'":"').replace(/\s/g,'') + '"}')

// {some1: "param1", some2: "param2"}
```

Answer (score 3):

If it is a one-liner you are after, the Underscore library has a pretty function called `object`, which takes an array of pairs and builds an object from it:

```
> _.object(["some","param"],["over","here"])
{some: "param", over: "here"}
```

If you use Underscore, you can one-line the construction of an object from your query string as follows:

```
> var s = 'some=param&over=here';
> _.object(s.split('&').map(function(p){return p.split('=');}))
{some: "param", over: "here"}
```

Now if all you want is the JavaScript object, you are done.  You said in your question that you wanted *JSON*, so the next step is pretty easy:

```
> JSON.stringify(_.object(s.split('&').map(function(p){return p.split('=');})))
"{\"some\": \"param\", \"over\": \"here\"}"
```

Here is a [live demo](http://jsbin.com/ihewiy/1/edit)

If you are not using Underscore, you can always write a utility function of your own.

This one line is a little ugly, but Firefox 22 has some of the upcoming ES6 features like array comprehensions and arrows, so the code can be made even more compact in the future, e.g.

```
JSON.stringify(_.object(s.split('&').map(p => p.split('='))))
```

or even

```
JSON.stringify(_.object([p.split('=') for (p of s.split('&'))]))
```

Or maybe just stick to the readable for loops and make your own function. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try use this function:

```
// Returns an object with elements "name: value" with data ftom URL (the "name=value" pairs)
function getDataUrl(url) {
 // From: http://coursesweb.net/javascript/
  var url_data = url.match(/\?([^#]*)/i)[1];          // gets the string between '?' and '#'

  // separate the data into an array, in case the are multiple pairs name=value
  var ar_url_data = url_data.split('&');

  // traverse the array, and adds into an object elements name:value
  var data_url = {};
  for(var i=0; i<ar_url_data.length; i++) {
    var ar_val = ar_url_data[i].split('=');           // separate name and value from each pair
    data_url[ar_val[0]] = ar_val[1];
  }

  return data_url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used [satpal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1668533/satpal)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17483258) to provide a nice Razor to JSON pipeline that works with `Html.BeginForm`, `@Html.TextBoxFor` etc.

The updated getUrlVars function looks like this:

```
function getUrlVars(url) {
    var hash;
    var myJson = {};
    var hashes = url.slice(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        var value = decodeURIComponent(hash[1]);
        value = value.replace("[\"", "");
        value = value.replace("\"]", "");
        value = value.replace(/\^.*/, "");
        myJson[hash[0]] = value;
    }
    return myJson;
}
```

The extra `replace` calls are for characters I get in my text boxes, probably via the dropdown `magicSuggest` lookups. The `decodeURIComponent` call cleans it up from %'s first.

I call it in a block like this:

```
    var serialized = $("#saveForm").serialize();
    var params = getUrlVars(serialized);
```

The Razor syntax I have looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveNewAddress", "Internal", FormMethod.Post, new { @Id = "saveForm" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <table style="width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; padding: 10px">

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <label>Is this a Liliputian Address?</label>
            </td>
            <td colspan="4" style="font-size: 1.1em">

                <div style="float: left; margin-left: 10px">
                    <label class="label_check">
                        @Html.RadioButton("IsLiliputian", "Yes", true, new { @id = "IsLiliputianYes", @style = "width:30px" })
                    </label>
                    Yes
                </div>
                ...etc
```

This provides a nice way to get a bunch of data created in and via ASP.Net MVC controls in a js object that I can throw at a webservice via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try something like

```
var url = require('url')
var your_json = url.parse( your_url, true );
```

I got this from [here](https://gist.github.com/asabaylus/1474983)

Answer (score 0):

```
function getFormData(data){
    data = data.replace('%20', ' ');
    var jsonObj= {};

    var sep = data.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sep.length; i++) {
        var getVals = sep[i].split('=');
        jsonObj[getVals[0]] = getVals[1];
    }
    return jsonObj;
}
```