# how to paramameters double name to json

Tags: javascript, json

I have a string like this:

```
abc=foo&chk_seq%5B%5D=5&chk_seq%5B%5D=7&xyz=5
```

(it comes from ajaxOptions.data parameter from the ajaxComplete event)

How can I convert it into a javascript object like this:

```
obj = {
  abc: 'foo',
  chk_seq[]: 5,
  chk_seq[]: 7,
  xyz: 5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[**First Google result**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483057/convert-url-to-json):

```
var params = getUrlVars('some=params&over=here');
console.log(params);

function getUrlVars(url) {
    var hash;
    var myJson = {};
    var hashes = url.slice(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        myJson[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return myJson;
}
```

It even has a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jAGN5/)!

**Update**:

I think this is what you may actually be looking for:

First google result for "[javascript convert url parameters to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648892/convert-url-parameters-to-a-javascript-object)":

```
var search = location.search.substring(1);
JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURI(search)
    .replace(/"/g, '\\"')
    .replace(/&/g, '","')
    .replace(/=/g,'":"') + '"}'
);
```

Comment: it's this
chk_seq%5B%5D=5&
chk_seq%5B%5D=7

this result

{abc: "foo", chk_seq%5B%5D: "7", xyz: "5"}

Comment: That's an URL enconded string of parameters as far as I know. JSFiddle is down so I can't check if this works for arrays too. Check my updated answer.

Comment: i do searching in googling... 
but all things don't like answer.

Comment: arielnmz  yea i tried the second code, but doesn't not multivalue.
result to chk_seq only singlevalue.