# Is there an equivalent of find_first_of c++ string method in javascript

Tags: javascript

I come from C++ background and currently working on node.js server app.
I want to know if there exists an equivalent of find_first_of C++ string class method in Javascript string.

Basically I'll have a string like 
`var str ="abcd=100&efgh=101&ijkl=102&mnop=103"`. The order of `&` seprated words could be random. So, I wanted to do something like the following:

```
str.substr(str.find("mnop=") + string("mnop=").length, str.find_first_of("&,\n'\0'")
```

Is there a way to it in a single line like above?

Comment: String's `indexOf`?

Comment: `indexOf` can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You may find the [search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) function useful.

```
"string find first find second".search("find"); // 7
```

In addition, you may also find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483057/convert-url-to-json) question useful.

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct equivalent, but you always can employ regular expressions:

```
var str ="abcd=100&efgh=101&ijkl=102&mnop=103";
console.log(str.match(/&mnop=([^&]+)/)[1]);
```

However, in this specific case, it's better to use the [dedicated module](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html):

```
var qs = require('querystring');
var vars = qs.parse(str);
console.log(vars.mnop);
```

If you really want a method that behaves like `find_first_of`, it can be implemented like this:

```
String.prototype.findFirstOf = function(chars, start) {
    var idx = -1;
    [].some.call(this.slice(start || 0), function(c, i) {
        if(chars.indexOf(c) >= 0)
            return idx = i, true;
    });
    return idx >= 0 ? idx + (start || 0) : -1;
}

console.log("abc?!def??".findFirstOf('?!'));    // 3
console.log("abc?!def??".findFirstOf('?!', 6)); // 8
```