# How to send json and parse it on next html page through url in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I want to send json data through url to next html page. I checked it by emulator as I am working for mobile app, the url could not redirect to next page it is crashing at the moment what is the reason behind this. How can I parse it on next page .I am new to the jquery any idea? my json data contains result of two different sql queries in an array

```
 $.ajax({
         type : "POST",
         datatype : "json",
         url : "http://Localhost/phpBB3/check_pass.php?username="+ username + "&password="+ password+"&f=68",
         success: function(data){
             alert(data);

               window.location.href="source/testmenu.html?varid=" + data +"&username=" + username +"&password=" + password;
        }
 });
```

This is the code on next page

```
$(document).ready(function GetUrlValue(VarSearch){
       var SearchString = window.location.search.substring(1);

       var arr = SearchString.split('&');
       console.log(arr);
       //Set session variables
       var username = arr[1].split('=')[1];
       var password = arr[2].split('=')[1];
       document.getElementById('username').value = username;
       document.getElementById('password').value = password;
)};
```

Comment: sending username and password in url is not recommended.

Comment: Why don't you just make the same call again on the second page? You could also store it in the localStorage. On page 1 : `localStorage.myJson = myJson;` On page 2 : `myJson = JSON.parse(localStorage.myJson);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your case in first page urlencode json

```
window.location.href="source/testmenu.html?varid=" + encodeURIComponent(data) +"&username=" + username +"&password=" + password;
```

and in next page

```
var data= arr[0].split('=')[1];
var recieved_json = $.parseJSON(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

Then try this one:

```
var data = {
    username: username,
    password: password
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://Localhost/phpBB3/check_pass.php",
    params: $.param(data),
    success: function(a) {
        window.location.href = "source/testmenu.html?"
            + $.param(a) + "&" + $.param(data)
    }
});
```

And this would be your code for the next page (the iterator is from Satpal's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17483258/4043409)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var params = window.location.search;

    var getURLParams = function(params) {
        var hash;
        var json = {};
        var hashes = url.slice(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            json[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
        return json;
    }

    params = getURLParams(params);

    var username = params.username;
    var password = params.password;
    $('#username').val(username);
    $('#password').val(password);
});
```

Though I agree with @Jai that *sending username and password in url is not recommended.*

Answer (score 1):

Once you get the URL to load you'll need to run your data through some encoding and decoding.  You might have the wrong path. If you want "http://Localhost/source/testmenu.html" make sure the first character is a "/".

Make sure your data object is encoded correctly.

```
// Encode data for querystring value.
var data = {
  foo: "bar"
};

var data_str = JSON.stringify(data);
data_str = encodeURIComponent(data_str);
```

Decode and test your URL.

```
// Get data from querystring value.

// Get the query as an object with decoded values.
// Note that JSON values still need parsing.
function getQuery() {
  var s=window.location.search;
  var reg = /([^?&=]*)=([^&]*)/g;
  var q = {};
  var i = null;

  while(i=reg.exec(s)) {
    q[i[1]] = decodeURIComponent(i[2]);
  }

  return q;
}

var q = getQuery();

try {
  var data = JSON.parse(q.data);
} catch (err) {
  alert(err + "\nJSON=" + q.data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameter should be html encode while navigating or requesting to the URL and decode at the receiving end. It may suspect potentially dangerous content which may leads to crash.

Comment: That does not answer OP's question.

Comment: we can send any kind of param he wants in this way.

Comment: In that case, I think you should write some code : show how you encode URL, explain what you mean.

Comment: encoding & decoding is everywhere on the net stuff. one can go through very easily.

For encoding,follow this
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp

For decoding, follow this
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp

Comment: I agree, but in that case, just write a comment. Don't formulate an official answer to the question, which is not an answer and just says "Google around for encoding and decoding".