# How to send & retrieve JSON Array to different JSP page using URL in Java Script

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, jsp

This is my code in ***A.jsp***

```js
$.ajax({ 
     method: "GET",
     url: "getMilestone",
     data: {"projectId" : projectId},
     traditional: true, 
     success:
      function(jsonArry){
       alert(jsonArry);
       window.location.href = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/B.jsp?jsonArry="+jsonArry;   
     },
     error: 
      function(){
       alert("fail");
      }
 });
```

It gives below alert

[image]

The fact I want want to know is How can I retrieve this *JSON array* in ***B.jsp***?

Comment: Eh, what about `request.getParameter("jsonArry");`? Anyway, this is a very unfortunate way to pass such complex parameters between JSP pages. You should (re)consider your architecture.

Comment: you should check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30498646/how-to-send-json-and-parse-it-on-next-html-page-through-url-in-jquery?noredirect=1&lq=1