# How to convert POST form data to JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, http, form-data

if there any default functions that can convert a post form data string into json object ?

Here is an example

```
sendNotification=true&type=extended&additionalNotes=&returnToMainPage=true
```

As you can this is the format of POST form data. I need to convert it into JSON object

```
{
    "sendNotification": "true",
    "type": "extended",
    "additionalNotes": "",
    "returnToMainPage": "true"
}
```

Also it should handle arrays like this

```
blog.blogposts[1].comments  1
blog.blogposts[1].likes 12
```

I wonder how can I do this using existing tools and libraries. I know that I can write my own converter, but I guess there should a default one.

Thanks

**IMPORTANT**

I don't have a form, I need just convert the form data string.

Comment: You can serialize the form data. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338774/serialize-form-data-to-json

Comment: Please check the tick mark, if answer helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var params = getUrlVars('some=params&over=here');
console.log(params);

function getUrlVars(url) {
    var hash;
    var myJson = {};
    var hashes = url.slice(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        myJson[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return myJson;
}
```

I found it here [Convert URL to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483057/convert-url-to-json)

Answer (score 1):

*I see it this way*

```
getStringJson('sendNotification=true&type=extended&additionalNotes=&returnToMainPage=true');

function getStringJson(text) {
    var json = {}, text = text.split("&");
    for (let i in text){
        let box = text[i].split("=");
        json[box[0]] = box[1];
    }
    return JSON.stringify(json);
}
```

*Output generated:*

```
"{"sendNotification":"true","type":"extended","additionalNotes":"","returnToMainPage":"true"}"
```

Answer (score 1):

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/pyd6p7op/)

```js
// Form Data String
var dataString = "sendNotification=true&type=extended&additionalNotes=&returnToMainPage=true";

// Split the String using String.split() method. It will return the array.
var params = dataString.split("&");

// Create the destination object.
var obj = {};

// iterate the splitted String and assign the key and values into the obj.
for (var i in params) {
  var keys = params[i].split("=");
  obj[keys[0]] = keys[1];
}

console.log(obj); // Object {sendNotification: "true", type: "extended", additionalNotes: "", returnToMainPage: "true"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer from Prashanth Reddy, if you want json string output simply add `JSON.stringify(myJson);` on the return

```
var params = getUrlVars('sendNotification=true&type=extended&additionalNotes=&returnToMainPage=true');
console.log(params);
function getUrlVars(url) {
    var hash;
    var myJson = {};
    var hashes = url.slice(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        myJson[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return JSON.stringify(myJson);
}
```

Output: `{"sendNotification":"true","type":"extended","additionalNotes":"","returnToMainPage":"true"}`